# Removing x number of characters from the caret position in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I am working on a project where the user can enter a special character and then tab to auto complete the values. This part is mostly working, but I want to be able to delete x number of characters from before the caret position. 
E.g. if `|` is the caret and I have the following text `@chr|`.

I want to be able to delete 3 characters before the cursor position, e.g. I would just end up with `@`.

I have found a way to get the current cursor position using the below code, but I haven't been able to find any way of being able to delete x number of characters from that position.

```
  function getCaretPosition()
        {
            var ed = tinyMCE.get('txtComment');     // get editor instance
            var range = ed.selection.getRng().startOffset;     // get range
            return range;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) ending at the current caret position:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get("mce_0"); // get editor instance
var editorRange = ed.selection.getRng(); // get range object for the current caret position

var node = editorRange.commonAncestorContainer; // relative node to the selection

range = document.createRange(); // create a new range object for the deletion
range.selectNodeContents(node);
range.setStart(node, editorRange.endOffset - 3); // current caret pos - 3 
range.setEnd(node, editorRange.endOffset); // current caret pos
range.deleteContents();

ed.focus(); // brings focus back to the editor
```

To use the demo, position the caret somewhere in the text and then click the "Remove 3" button at the top to delete the preceding 3 characters.

Note that my demo is simplified and doesn't do any bounds checking.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWVWYM?editors=0010

Compatibility is IE9+

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I'll reward you the bounty but I have to wait 9 hours

Comment: it is not working when reach last character of a line and it has characters in the above lines.