# Putting caret position at end of the text in Tiny MCE Editor on keyPress event

Tags: tinymce-4

I have a requirement on entering space after a text is entered spell check service is called and the caret/cursor is positioned at start of the text. I want caret to be positioned at the end of the text and not start of the text in Tiny MCE Editor. Tried some suggestions but of no help.

Comment: @K Scandrett I found your answer to the post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736011/removing-x-number-of-characters-from-the-caret-position-in-tinymce) to be useful but when i am trying to run it on keyDown event of Tiny MCE Editor and after entering space it deletes 3 characters again the whole word comes back and caret is placed at start of the editor and cannot put it anywhere on the editor. Basically, i am trying to put caret at end of the typed word with space on keyPress event of Tiny MCE Editor.

Comment: I am working on spell check requirement and making an ajax call to call web api which checks the spelling on keyPress event in Tiny MCE Editor and observed that after making that ajax call the cursor is at start of the word and cannot move the cursor.